# Ruby on rails app works on local host but, not on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, localhost

I just learn ruby on rails. I created two database table: trainers and tokimons. Everything works fine on local host(including database), but something went wrong on heroku.

Here is the log:

```
2016-10-13T21:51:16.840425+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=a2-tokimon.herokuapp.com request_id=2f86b075-8d64-4616-984a-304df86d9768 fwd="142.58.35.51" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=11ms status=500 bytes=1669

2016-10-13T21:51:16.851541+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 142.58.35.51 at 2016-10-13 21:51:16 +0000

2016-10-13T21:51:16.854395+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML

2016-10-13T21:51:16.858208+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered welcome/index.erb within layouts/application (3.1ms)

2016-10-13T21:51:16.858340+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 2.3ms)

2016-10-13T21:51:16.859867+00:00 app[web.1]: 

2016-10-13T21:51:16.859872+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "trainers" does not exist

2016-10-13T21:51:16.859873+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: SELECT "trainers".* FROM "trainers"

2016-10-13T21:51:16.859874+00:00 app[web.1]:                                  ^

2016-10-13T21:51:16.859874+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT "trainers".* FROM "trainers"):

2016-10-13T21:51:16.859875+00:00 app[web.1]:     51: 

2016-10-13T21:51:16.859876+00:00 app[web.1]:     52: 

2016-10-13T21:51:16.859877+00:00 app[web.1]:     53:           <tbody>

2016-10-13T21:51:16.859877+00:00 app[web.1]:     54:             <% @trainer.each do |trainer| %>

2016-10-13T21:51:16.859878+00:00 app[web.1]:     55:               <tr class="<%= cycle('oddline', 'evenline') %>">

2016-10-13T21:51:16.859879+00:00 app[web.1]:     56:                 <td><%= trainer.pname %></td>

2016-10-13T21:51:16.859880+00:00 app[web.1]:     57:                 <td><%= trainer.level %></td>

2016-10-13T21:51:16.859881+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/welcome/index.erb:54:in `_app_views_welcome_index_erb__3990380873615253162_69847032979680'

2016-10-13T21:51:16.859882+00:00 app[web.1]: 

2016-10-13T21:51:16.859882+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

Here is a portion of trainers_controller.rb

```
class TrainersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_trainer, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /trainers
  # GET /trainers.json
  def index
    @trainer = Trainer.all
  end
```

Here is a portion of welcome_controller.rb

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController

  # GET /welcome
  def index
    @trainer = Trainer.all
  end



end
```

Comment: You gotta rake the database for heroku to make the tables. If you have the heroku cli run `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. If I had to guess I'd say you had forgotten to check in the migration (or schema) - because basically your database is missing the trainers table.

Comment: Thank you guys. I will try it. By the way, I used : rails generate scaffold Trainer pname:string ****** to create table. But when to use Trainer, trainer and trainers makes me confuse. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

the line:

`2016-10-13T21:51:16.859872+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "trainers" does not exist` should be a hint that you have a postgres issue. Specifically that the tables are undefined.

Assuming you have heroku-cli installed, you'll need to run `heroku run rake db:migrate` in the console this will perform the migrations needed for Heroku.

Here is the documentation on how to get a Rails (4) app running on Heroku:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4

And specifically here is the part about migrations:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4#migrate-your-database

Heroku CLI documentation and installation instructions:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-command-line

Answer (score 0):

`PG::UndefinedTable` and `PG::UndefinedColumn` errors occur because you have not run the migrations against the production database.

You should make a habit of running `heroku run rake:db:migrate` after each deployment.